# PHP - good practice reading POST variables

Tags: php

I am thinking of a good practice to read the client submitted POST data.

For example if I have a post variable that should have the following structure:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
      ['test'] => array(1, 2, 3),
      ['test2'] => "string"
    ),
    [1] => array(
        ['test'] => array(),
        ['test2'] => "string2"
    ),
)
```

Where the indices 'test' and 'test2' should always be present but their values may be empty (array() and "");
The functions that handle the POST data are expecting the correct format, so I have to make sure that the data has not been manipulated.

I could do the following:

```
$result = array();
if(isset($_POST['myVar']) && is_array($_POST['myVar'])) {
    foreach($_POST['myVar'] as $array) {
        $new = array('test' => array(), 'test2' = "");
        if(isset($array['test']) && is_array($array['test'])) {
            foreach($array['test'] as $expectedInt) {
                $new['test'][] = (int)$expectedInt;
            }
        }


        if(isset($array['test2']) && is_string($array['test2']))
            $new['test2'] = $array['test2'];
    }

    $result[] = $new;
}
```

I think you get the idea what I mean. I wonder if there is a better practice of reading the POST data into the expected format.

Comment: How about sending the data in JSON format and then using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the server to turn it into a PHP object.

Comment: @Expert Sorry, but that's the most useless suggestion here. You will *still* need to *validate* the received data on the server.

Comment: @deceze: Thx for pointing out the "useless" part. Still it is a lot more easier to _validate_ a PHP object, than build it yourself through multiple `forEach` loops. But maybe you have a better suggestion.

Comment: When you getting **empty** `$_POST['myVar']`, there will occur an error:  `Notice:  Undefined variable: new`

Comment: Use Regular Expressions to validate format.

Comment: @Expert So what's the difference between `$needsValidation = $_POST` and `$needsValidation = json_decode($_POST['json'])`? You still need *some* validation code on an unknown data structure.

Comment: @Jorge A regex to validate an array...?!?

Comment: @deceze The guy wants to validate format of variables. If the variables are inside an array that's irrelevant. He is always expecting 2 variables inside an array, and correctly formatted. So, check for that 2 variables, and then check it's format. If there are more variables than needed, that's irrelevant too.

Comment: @CetraiN: Thanks, corrected it like you suggested

Comment: I deleted `(string)` casting and added `is_string()` checking. Because `(string)$arr` causes `Notice:  Array to string conversion`

Comment: In the first place, how did multi-dimensional arrays end up in the `$_POST` variable (unless some JSON encoding/decoding is involved) ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem No Problem: <input name="myVar[0][test2]" value="abc" /> and so on...

Comment: @schlimpf: Cool ! I did know I could pass an array, but I didn't know it worked _multi-dimensionaly_ too (shame). Thx !

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this to assure I have default indices:

```
$par = $_POST;
$par += [
   'key' => 'default',
   'other' => 'default',
]
```

If `$par` doesn't contain those keys, they are set.

In your case, your could do this:

```
$ready = [];
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
   $v += [
     'test' => [],
     'test2' => "string2",
   ];
   // Validate if needed
   $v['test'] = (array)$v['test'];
   $v['test2'] = (string)$v['test2'];

   $ready[$k] = $v;
}
```

Later you can be sure, that `$ready` will contain values with `test` and `test2` keys.

This is very useful in functions, where you replace a lot of arguments with one parameter array, and then later set default values,

Comment: The `$v+=` appears to be giving an `Unsupported operand types` error. Any idea why ?

Comment: @JamesPoulson It could be that your server doens't support shorthand arrays. Try to replace `[..]` with classic `array(..)` definition.